# Scheduled batch script stuck on running

Tags: batch-file, task

I have a script while ran from a CMD runs normally, however when I run it from task scheduler although it does everything as intended, the script status hangs on "Running"

Here is the script:

```
    @echo OFF
    tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq utorrent.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "utorrent.exe">NUL
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (echo UTorrent is running nothing to do) ELSE (
    echo UTorrent is not running, starting Utorrent!
    start C:\Users\Adonis\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe
    )

    tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq steam.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "steam.exe">NUL
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (echo Steam is running nothing to do) ELSE (
    echo Steam is not running, starting Steam!
    start X:\Games\SteamLibrary\Steam.exe
    )

    exit
```

Can anyone advise why this is happening? IE why is the script stuck in running state through scheduler?

The OS in question is windows 8.
It is set to run only when user is logged on and with highest privileges.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch the application with the /B parameter to don't stop the execution of he script.

Also I've improved the syntax of your code:

```
@echo OFF

(Tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq utorrent.exe" | find /I "utorrent.exe">NUL && (
    Echo: UTorrent is running nothing to do)
) || (
    Echo: UTorrent is not running, starting Utorrent!
    Start /B "" "C:\Users\Adonis\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe"
)

(Tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq steam.exe" | find /I "steam.exe">NUL && (
    Echo: Steam is running nothing to do)
) || (
    Echo: Steam is not running, starting Steam!
    Start /B "" "X:\Games\SteamLibrary\Steam.exe"
)

Exit
```